# Hudson authentication via wget is return http error 302

Tags: http, redirect, hudson

I'm trying to make a script to authenticate in hudson using wget and store the authentication cookie.

The contents of the script is this:

```
wget \
--no-check-certificate \
--save-cookies /home/hudson/hudson-authentication-cookie \
--output-document "-" \
'https://myhudsonserver:8443/hudson/j_acegi_security_check?j_username=my_username&j_password=my_password&remember_me=true'
```

Unfortunately, when I run this script, I get:

```
--2011-02-03 13:39:29--  https://myhudsonserver:8443/hudson/j_acegi_security_check?     j_username=my_username&j_password=my_password&remember_me=true
Resolving myhudsonserver... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to myhudsonserver|127.0.0.1|:8443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify myhudsonserver's certificate, issued by `/C=Unknown/ST=Unknown/L=Unknown/O=Unknown/OU=Unknown/CN=myhudsonserver':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://myhudson:8443/hudson/;jsessionid=087BD0B52C7A711E0AD7B8BD4B47585F    [following]
--2011-02-03 13:39:29--      https://myhudsonserver:8443/hudson/;jsessionid=087BD0B52C7A711E0AD7B8BD4B47585F
Reusing existing connection to myhudsonserver:8443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-02-03 13:39:29 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

There's no error log in any of hudson's tomcat log files.

Does anyone has any idea about what might be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the equivalent using curl:

```
curl --cookie-jar /home/hudson/hudson-authentication-cookie \
     --data-urlencode "j_username=my_username" \
     --data-urlencode "j_password=my_password" \
     --data-urlencode "remember_me=true" \
     --insecure https://myhudsonserver:8443/hudson/j_acegi_security_check
```

This should work, although depending on what you really need to do, there may be a better approach.

In particular if you just need a single query, include a "from=/hudson/..." in the form data so that the 302 redirect leads to the resource that you're actually interested in.  If you add --location, curl will follow the 302 redirect and will use the cookies (--cookie-jar is still required, unfortunately).  This makes a nice one-liner:

```
curl --cookie-jar /home/hudson/hudson-authentication-cookie \
     --data-urlencode "j_username=my_username" \
     --data-urlencode "j_password=my_password" \
     --data-urlencode "from=/hudson/view/myview/api/json" \
     --insecure --location https://myhudsonserver:8443/hudson/j_acegi_security_check
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work. I end up doing the script in perl and www::mechanize. Thanks!